# json_encode not working in my wamp

Tags: php, wamp, json

Good day, I have a question with regards to the json_encode function. I searched the web for answers about this however, all of them says that json_encode function can be used in PHP 5.3. I am using PHP 5.3 in a wamp server, however whenever I write this code

echo json_encode($months);

where months is:

```
   $months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July","August",
"September","October","November","December");
```

I am always getting "Unexpected T_ECHO" error. Can anyone inform me if I am missing something?

Comment: Can you show the code before that line? The problem is likely to be there.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Indeed it is, I realized that there is no semi colon on my previous statement. I realized it when Ignacio gave me an answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've goofed up on the previous line. Check for a missing semicolon.

Comment: WHAT THE FRIDGE. THANK YOU SIR VERY MUCH FOR SAVING ME FROM MY MISERABLE AFTERNOON. was looking at the json line for quite some time, didnt realize the previous line.. THANKS A MILLION

Comment: (someone flagged this incorrectly. I rejected the flagging but you may like to expand the answer, Ignacio, to avoid someone else flagging it.)

Comment: I'm not really sure what potential flaggers want to see. An example of a line without a semicolon at the end? A link to an article explaining statement termination in PHP? A 2000-word essay on the history of statement termination in various languages? This answer is precise, accurate, and correct.